# calculate percent with php and json output

Tags: php, json, mysqli, sum

I would like to calculate percent of sumed values, grouped by categories. This is my current code:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$rezultat = "SELECT sum(values) as values, categories FROM values WHERE username = '$username' AND cas between '".date("Y-m-01")."' AND '".date("Y-m-31 23:59:59")."' group by categories";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $result2) or die (mysqli_error($link));

$array = array();
$array["name"] = "Categories";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$array["data"][] = array($row["categories"], $row["values"]);
}

echo json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Sumed values are in perfect form for displaying it with highcharts:

```
{
    "name": "Kategorije",
    "data": [
        ["Cigareti", 97.5],
        ["Drogerija", 30],
        ["Elektrika", 20.6],
        ["Gorivo", 54],
        ["Internet", 6],
        ["Komunalne storitve", 15.6],
        ["Malica", 60.02],
        ["Oblacila", 70],
        ["RTV Slovenija", 6.3],
        ["Sport", 15],
        ["Tehnika", 96],
        ["Trgovina", 269.99],
        ["Upravnik", 50],
        ["Voda", 7.6],
        ["Vrtec", 204.14],
        ["Zabava", 50]
    ]
}
```

Now, I would like to calculate percent from this values. Any idea how to start this?

Answer (score 1):

Sum all the values (as in, 97.5 + 30 + 20.6 ..) you will now have the sum, name it X. Now all you need to do is loop again over all the values and divide each value by X * 100, that is, (Value/X) * 100.